# using provide in closure library

Tags: namespaces, google-closure-library

I'm very newbie in closure,
I'm reading the tutorial at: https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/tutorial
and it says that

```
goog.provide('tutorial.notepad.Note');
```

is equivalent to

```
tutorial = tutorial || {};
tutorial.notepad = tutorial.notepad || {};
tutorial.notepad.Note = tutorial.notepad.Note || {};
```

basing on that fact, I assume that if use    `goog.provide('tutorial.notepad.Note');`

then there is no need to use         `goog.provide('tutorial.notepad);`

but the example uses both of them together.
may somebody explain to me why?

Answer (score 1):

`goog.provide(namespace)`  will check each dot-delimited name starting on the left and create a property pointing to a new object literal equivalent to the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/tutorial) excerpt you provided above. Therefore, you are correct that [notepad.js](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/samples/notepad.js) does not technically need to include `goog.provide('tutorial.notepad')`, since `goog.provide('tutorial.notepad.Note')` will ensure that the object chain `tutorial.notepad` exists.

However, in addition to defining a `Note` object with member function `makeNoteDom`, notepad.js also defines a utility function `makeNotes`, which is a member of the `tutorial.notepad` namespace. By including `goog.provide(tutorial.notepad)`, it indicates that notepad.js provides package-level functionality in addition to defining a `Note` object.

Comment: Thank you cpeisert. I don't know why don't they have the ability to add comments on their tutorials. that would be of great benefit, and would cover for such questions.

Comment: @cpeisert so would it be wise to always define the namespace up not, but no including any objects? For example, even if tutorial.notepad.Note was the only thing declared and defined in notepad.js, simply use goog.provide('namespace.notepad'); ??

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira I recommend studying the [Closure Library code](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/#git%2Fclosure%2Fgoog). You will find that the namespace is almost always declared using `goog.provide` followed by additional `goog.provide` statements for each object defined within the namespace in the same file.

Comment: @christopher-peisert I have noticed that. But based on the way goog.provide appears to work, it sort of seems redundant to call goog.provide to specify every attribute to be added to the namespace object. Is calling goog.provide for every property **required** for something down the line (maybe goog.require ?), or would it work out to simply add a single goog.provide call for the package level declaration, and let the compiler/IDE figure out all the properties defined for that object? I've seen people do it both ways, but my question is about best practice & requirements, not mere convention.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira The coding conventions adopted by the Closure Library and the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) are the currently accepted best practices for using Closure Library primitives such as `goog.provide` and `goog.require`. Also see the [comments for `goog.provide`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_base.js.source.html#line97) in base.js.